# Deploying rails application bitnami rubystack GoDaddy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, deployment, bitnami

I am new to using stacks such as those from Bitnami. I recently created a Bitnami RubyStack on GoDaddy, cloned my repository and did all the house cleaning. When i SSH into the server and run `rails s -b MY_PUBLIC_ip -p PORT` in the application directory and i open the browser, it works perfectly fine but when i close the SSH session and point to the same address there is nothing. The public IP still shows the welcome page. I think i misunderstood the whole concept. Can someone please help teach me how it is done. Thanks in advance.

**Update**
I heard something about creating virtual hosts but cant understand how the `rails s` command will run. Is it possible to start the server and it continues running even when the SSH session is closed.

Comment: When you close your laptop the SSH connection is closed. Did you checkout Screen? Via screen you can start the server and close the SSH connection. Maybe I miss understood your question tho, because I now see that you are still able to see the welcome page from your Rails application.

Comment: what is checkout screen

Comment: It's Screen, not checkout Screen, my bad. Screen is a tool where you can connect into a server via SSH, start it and exit the connection. Normally when you connect via SSH, and close it afterwards the server is destroyed with it.

Comment: I am using normal SSH on linux

Comment: Thanks though i found this link about www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keep-your-ssh-session-running-when-you-disconnect/ so i will check it out and see if it solves anything.

Comment: I don't know and haven't used Bitnami but do you really have to run `rails s` yourself to start the server? Isn't it already configured to work with apache or nginx with something like Passenger?

Comment: Simply you need to process the server in background so that it can't be stop if you closed the terminal as well.https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/rails/

Answer (score 0):

That's completely fine (using Linux to connect via SSH, the principle remains the same), I think you misunderstand what Screen actually does (might be my explanation of it). You can still connect normally via SSH. So let's say `ssh name@ip`. After installing `screen` with: `apt-get install screen` you can type `screen` (within your SSH session). After this type the command to start the server like you normally would: `rails s -b MY_PUBLIC_ip -p PORT`. Now type: `ctrl + a` and after `d` (detach but keep shell window open). Now you can kill the SSH connection and the server is still alive. If you want to re-open the server again via the SSH connection you use `screen -r` to open the last session(the one you just started)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `rails` to deploy your application and `screen` to keep it running once you close the SSH connection, you can consider the next alternative:

Bitnami Rubystack includes apache and nginx servers installed as a service so as long as your instance is running, these servers (one or another) will be running too. You can configure on of those web servers to deploy your application and it will be ready for production. You can see how to configure these web servers [in this link](https://docs.bitnami.com/godaddy/infrastructure/ruby/#how-to-deploy-a-new-rails-application)